# Plesk - Applying configuration - command

Tags: php, linux, configuration, plesk

I am trying to apply changes in a vhost.conf file, according to the instructions [here](http://enarion.net/web/plesk/subdomains-and-open_basedir/) and [here](http://www.toosweettobesour.com/2008/02/02/plesk-open_basedir-workaround/). I am therefore running the following command:

```
    /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/websrvmng -u -–vhost-name=example.com
```

But nothing seems to happen when I do this, and the problem I had before making these changes is still in effect, so I believe the changes to the configuration are not being applied when I use this command. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I asked the more detailed question to this same problem, which caused me to try and use this command. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460614/php-cron-problems-using-plesk-dynamic-library-open-basedir).
And it is solved in another way, through entering a different command altogether to the command line, it by-passes the basedir problem. 
However I was still unable to apply the configuration I request in this question (but solved through a workaround).