# PHP Cron Problems - using plesk: dynamic library, open_basedir

Tags: php, cron, plesk

I entered the following command through plesk (control panel) crontab, to run a php file once an hour:

```
php httpdocs/cron/script.php
```

And I am getting the following 2 error messages (once an hour, to my email):

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/http.so' -
/usr/lib/php/modules/http.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in
Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
File(../include/functions.php) is not within the allowed path(s):
(/var/www/vhosts/basedomain.com:/tmp) in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/cron/script.php
on line 2
PHP Warning:  require_once(../include/functions.php): failed to open stream: Operation not
permitted in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/cron/script.php on line 2
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '../include/functions.php'
(include_path='.:') in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/cron/script.php on line 2
```

Note: Line 2 has `require_once(../include/functions.php);`

I realized these are 2 different issues. I tried solving each separately and they are both still with me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run PHP like this, configuration set in Plesk-specific and Apache-specific places like vhost.conf doesn't apply.

Since your script is already inside httpdocs, why don't you just use wget/curl to invoke the script through HTTP? Something like `/usr/bin/curl http://yoursite.com/cron/script.php 2>&1`. Might want to consider some additional validation (IP limiting, htpasswd auth) to make sure random visitors (script kiddies) can't run it.

Comment: Hi, I made a mistake when copying, it is not inside the same domain: there is basedomain.com, and then there is example.com; also, I am not sure whether your suggestion is for the crontab or to include in the script?

Comment: @LucyWeatherford: that suggestion is for crontab. But now that you've changed the question, I would first make sure that the script works correctly when opened in your browser, and only then add it to crontab.

Comment: thank you!! your code works awesomely!! the second problem is now solved, I don't know whatt to make of the first one yet, but it works it works it works. thank you!!

Comment: btw, what does the `2>&1` stand for?

Comment: @LucyWeatherford: most UNIX programs print normal output to a stream called STDOUT, and error messages to a stream called STDERR. By default, the email you receive contains only STDOUT. `2>&1` redirects the STDERR stream to STDOUT, this way the email contains them both.

Comment: thankyou! that's awesome. def need the errors :) btw see the continuing discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462208/curl-shell-php-cron-results)

Answer (score 1):

Please check below, maybe it will help you.
http://www.geeklog.net/forum/viewtopic.php?showtopic=28107

Comment: thanks, I tried doing what they write there yesterday, found the instructions elsewhere as well. I tried again now, but it didn't seem to go anywhere or solve it either. I tried the code \Dcoder gave me and it solved the second problem though. yay..