# Curl shell php cron results

Tags: php, shell, cron

I am receiving the following in my email every time the cron job is running:

What does it mean? Is something wrong? Why am I receiving this message?

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

0     6    0     6    0     0     22      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    22
0     6    0     6    0     0     22      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you actually stated what was in the cronjob.

Comment: curl is used to get info from the web - I'm not sure if it has anything to do with php and cron unless you wrote a script in php that is scheduled in cron and which uses curl: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html  it can be helpful if you'll post the line that you run from crontab and if it's a call to a script - then post the code as well.

Comment: @Amber and alfasin, good point, see the line I ran in crontab in the comments below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to pass `-s` to `curl` if you're running it via the command line, to tell it to be silent and not output progress information to the terminal.

Pass `-S` as well (e.g. `curl -s -S`) to make it show error messages if it encounters them, even though you've otherwise silenced it.

Comment: my code is `/usr/bin/curl http://mydomain.com/cron/script.php 2>&1`, so should I change it to: `/usr/bin/curl -s -S http://mydomain.com/cron/script.php 2>&1`

Comment: Yes, Lucy - that is exactly what you'd want to change it to.

Answer (score 1):

Run with arguments eg: `curl --silent yourscript.php`

`-s, --silent`

Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages. Makes Curl mute.

`-S, --show-error`

When used with -s it makes curl show an error message if it fails.

check http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html for more options.

Comment: my code is `/usr/bin/curl http://mydomain.com/cron/script.php 2>&1`, so should I change it to: `/usr/bin/curl -s -S http://mydomain.com/cron/script.php 2>&1`